# Socket.io: IE fires reconnecting event only once

Tags: node.js, internet-explorer, sockets, socket.io, reconnect

I have an app with node.js/socket.io running fine. Every time a client looses connection, it tries to reconnect using socket.io predefined process for that:

```
var io = io.connect("/", {
    'reconnect': true,
    'reconnection delay': 1000,
    'reconnection limit': 5000,
    'max reconnection attempts': 100
});
```

This works fine for all browsers except Internet Explorer. I added some alerts on all reconnecting events to check where the problem might be:

```
io.on('disconnect', function(){ alert('Disconnected!'); });
io.on('reconnect_failed', function(){ alert('FAILED'); });
io.on('reconnect', function(){ alert('OK'); });
io.on('reconnecting', function( nextRetry ){ alert('Reconnecting...'); });
```

When I stop socket.io server (or client connection is lost), all clients get the 'on disconnect' message. No problem with that.

### **Clients with other than IE**

> All clients keep getting the 'Reconnecting...' message every 5 seconds 
>   until connection has been restored, and if so, they get the final OK message.

### **Clients with IE**

> If server is still down by the time IE tries to reconnect (the first
>   time), client does not continue trying to reconnect, and even when
>   server is up again users will never be connected until refresh of
>   page. Since disconnect event, clients get the "Reconnecting..."
>   message only once.

Just as a plus test, if server is restored before IE client tries to reconnect, then client get reconnected with success.

I found this problem here: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/1020. But they to not come to a solution. I serve the socket.io.js file dinamically, so I cannot edit it the way they suggest.

Thanks!

Comment: Which IE version are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I worked around this issue for socket.io 0.9.6 / ie8:

```
  var _socket = io.connect();
  ...
  _socket.on('disconnect', function(){
      var interval = setInterval(function () {
          if (_socket.socket.connected) {
              clearInterval(interval);
          } else {
              _socket.socket.disconnect();
              _socket.socket.reconnect();
          }
      }, 31000);
  });
```

31 seconds interval is needed for the previous jsonp script inserted into document to time out, othervise multiple connect events are triggered (multiple sockets get connected) when server becomes available..